# Amazon CloudFront not showing updated headers in S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Amazon CloudFront with the files coming from Amazon S3.  I wasn't originally setting the Amazon S3 Metadata to send a Cache-Control header, but I changed it a few weeks ago.  Most of the images are showing with the new header.  However, I have some that still do not.

For example if I hit this
https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/channelnet-useast-prod/Themes/Default/Images/phone.png, I see

```
Cache-Control:max-age=86400
```

But if I go to the CloudFront URL that points to that S3 image
http://dfb8oqhjho7zs.cloudfront.net/Themes/Default/Images/phone.png, I do not.

As a test, I made a copy of the image, uploaded it to S3, set the Cache-Control header, and verified the header is set when I access it via S3 
https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/channelnet-useast-prod/Themes/Default/Images/phone-matttest.png
or CloudFront
http://dfb8oqhjho7zs.cloudfront.net/Themes/Default/Images/phone-matttest.png

How do I get CloudFront to refresh whatever Amazon-side caching is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [clear/invalidate the CloudFront cache](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) so that it will check your origin for updates.

Comment: That worked. I went to CloudFront Distributions->Invalidations->Create Invalidation, entered * and clicked invalidate.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp5ji.png